# What does continuity of inclusion means?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $A,B,C$ are three spaces such that $A\subset B\subset C$ and $A$ is dense in $C$. Now my teacher said that the inclusion between three spaces are continuous and so you can directly say that $B$ is dense in $C$ .

When i asked  him why can't you directly conclude this, he said that the topologies are different and so you need the condition that the inclusions are continuous. I didn't understand what he meant by that?

Comment: By "the topologies are different" did he mean that the topologies on $A$ and $B$ are not the subspace topologies from the topology on $C$?  If they're not the subspace topology, we'd have to know what they are in order to say whether the inclusions are continuous with respect to them.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: Just to make things more precise, let's say that we're dealing with spaces $\langle A,\tau_A\rangle,$ $\langle B,\tau_B\rangle,$ and $\langle C,\tau_C\rangle,$ where $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. In that case, you are quite correct that there is no need to know anything about the continuity of the inclusions. In fact, we don't even need to know anything at all about the topologies $\tau_A$ or $\tau_B$.

Given a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ and any $S\subseteq X$, observe that there is at least one $V\in\tau$ such that $S\cap V=\emptyset$--for example, $V=\emptyset$--and we denote/define the *closure of $S$ in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$* by $$\text{cl}(S,X,\tau):=\bigcap\{X\smallsetminus V:V\in\tau,S\cap V=\emptyset\}.$$ This has the following properties (that you should verify):

> (i) $S\subseteq\text{cl}(S,X,\tau)\subseteq X.$
>
> (ii) $\text{cl}(S,X,\tau)$ is closed in $\langle X,\tau\rangle.$
>
> (iii) If $F\subseteq X$ with $F$ closed in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ and $S\subseteq F$, then $\text{cl}(S,X,\tau)\subseteq F$.

Putting (i)-(iii) together, it means that $\text{cl}(S,X,\tau)$ is the smallest subset of $X$ containing $S$ that is closed in $\langle X,\tau\rangle.$ Another property that you should verify is that $S\subseteq X$ is dense in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ if and only if $\text{cl}(S,X,\tau)=X$.

By way of contradiction, suppose that $B$ is not dense in $\langle C,\tau_C\rangle,$ so that there is some $c\in C$ such that $c\notin\text{cl}(B,C,\tau_C),$ meaning by definition of $\text{cl}(B,C,\tau_C)$ that there is thus some $V_0\in\tau_C$ with $B\cap V_0=\emptyset$, such that $c\notin C\smallsetminus V_0$. Now, since $B\cap V_0=\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cap V_0=\emptyset$. But then by definition of $\text{cl}(A,C,\tau_C),$ we have that $$\text{cl}(A,C,\tau_C)\subseteq C\smallsetminus V_0,$$ so $c\notin\text{cl}(A,C,\tau_C),$ contradicting our assumption that $A$ is dense in $\langle C,\tau_C\rangle.$ Another way to approach it is to show that if $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, then $\text{cl}(A,C,\tau_C)\subseteq\text{cl}(B,C,\tau_C),$ so if $A$ is dense in $\langle C,\tau_C\rangle,$ then $$C=\text{cl}(A,C,\tau_C)\subseteq\text{cl}(B,C,\tau_C)\subseteq C,$$ so $\text{cl}(B,C,\tau_C)=C$, as desired.

---

It is possible that, instead, your teacher meant that $A,B,C$ are spaces and that there exist injections $\iota_1:A\hookrightarrow B$ and $\iota_2:B\hookrightarrow C$, with $A$ *densely imbedded* into $C$ by $\iota_2\circ\iota_1$. That means that $\iota_2\circ\iota_1(A)$ dense in $C$, and that $\iota_2\circ\iota_1$ maps $A$ *homeomorphically* to $\iota_2\circ\iota_1(A)$, with the latter considered as a subspace of $\langle C,\tau_C\rangle.$ Since $$\iota_2\circ\iota_1(A)=\iota_2\bigl(\iota_1(A)\bigr)\subseteq\iota_2(B),$$ we can through the same sort of arguments conclude that $\iota_2(B)$ is dense in $C$, and we already know that $\iota_2:B\hookrightarrow C$ is an injection, but to be able to conclude that $B$ is densely imbedded into $C$, then we also need to know that $\iota_2$ is continuous (among other things). That may have been what was meant.

Comment: You can't say that $A\subset B \implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$ if $A\subset B$ is not a subspace. Teacher is correct.

Comment: @GastónBurrull: By definition, $\overline A$ is the smallest closed subset of $C$ containing $A$, and $\overline B$ is the smallest closed subset of $C$ containing $B$. Since $A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline B$, then $\overline B$ is a closed subset of $C$ containing $A$, whence $\overline A\subseteq\overline B$ by definition of $\overline A$.

Comment: Closed respect which topology?

Comment: With respect to the topology of $C$.

Comment: Then you're saying that $A$ and $B$ are considered as subspaces of $C$, and you wrote exactly the opposite.

Comment: I am not even *discussing* how $A$ and $B$ are topologized, so I'm *certainly* not asserting that we are considering them in the subspace topology. I am only considering the underlying sets $A,B$, and the topology of their mutual superset, $C$. As I said, by definition, $\overline A$ and $\overline B$ are the smallest subsets of $C$ that contain $A$ and $B$ (respectively) and are closed in $C$. Since we know that $A\subseteq B$, then it follows by definition that $\overline A\subseteq\overline B$, as I discussed above.

Comment: You are considering $A$ as a subspace of $C$ when you say that $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed subset of $C$ *that contains $A$*. You're doing an inclusion between A and C without mentioning it. You cant conclude $\overline{A}\subset C$ without using continuity of the inclusion map.

Comment: What means "the subset $X$ of $C$ is the minimal closed subset of $C$ that contains $A$"?
What is $A$ when we work with a topology on $C$? A subespace of $C$. You are using this fact, just need to mention it and answer is completely right. But when you said that "whether as subspaces or otherwise" this is completely wrong.

Comment: I am considering $A$ only as a **subset** of $C$, not a subspace. My conclusions follow by definition. Note that every subset $S$ of $C$ is contained in some closed subset of $C$--in particular, $C$, itself--and intersections of closed sets are closed. We can equivalently define the *closure of $S$ in $C$*--which I will denote $\overline S$--by $$\overline S:=\bigcap\{F\subseteq C:S\subseteq F,F\text{ closed in }C\}.$$ Then **by definition**, $\overline S\subseteq C$ for any $S\subseteq C$, and if $F\subseteq C$ is closed in $C$, then $S\subseteq F\Rightarrow\overline S\subseteq F$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7669/discussion-between-cameron-buie-and-gaston-burrull)

Answer (score 3):

Any inclusion of sets $X\subseteq Y$ can be seen as an injective map $\iota: X\to Y$ (simply given by $\iota(x) = x$ which makes sense since $x$ is also an element of $Y$).

The condition mentioned then is that this map is continuous, ie that we have chosen a topology on the subset such that this holds (typically, we will pick the subset topology, since this will make it hold).

Answer (score 1):

Cameron [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7669/discussion-between-cameron-buie-and-gaston-burrull) made ​​me realize that there are two valid answers to this question depending of which is your conceptual definition of *density*.

Let $X$ be a topologycal space

**First definition:**

> A subspace $A$ of $X$ is called **dense** in $X$ if the closure of $A$ respect $X$ is all of $X$.

This definition probably use your teacher. In this case we need considering a subset $A'\subset X$ equipped with a subspace topology, namely, that the inclusion map between topological spaces $i:A'\to X$ be continuous. Let $A=i(A')$ and you must show that $\overline{i(A')}=X$ (closure respect $X$).

In this case your teacher is right.

**Second definition:**

> A subset $A$ of $X$ is called **dense** in $X$ if the closure of $A$ respect $X$ is all of $X$.

This definition differs from the preceding only in a conceptual fact. Given the subset $A\subset X$. You only must to show that $\overline{A}=X$ (closure respect $X$). And you are right.

---

In practice both definitions bring same consequences and do not change any topological facts. All topology is the same in both cases since you can always identify a subset of a topological space with the respective induced subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

Teacher is right. If $A\subset B$ then $i_{A\to B}\colon A\to B$ is continuous iff $A$ is subspace of $B$.

Comment: You might want to add further details/proof about why that is the case. Regards

Comment: I explained my approach with a quite different answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. Consider $A$ as your favorite multi-element set in the discrete topology, and $B$ as that same set in the trivial (indiscrete) topology. In general, an inclusion map $\iota:A\to B$ is continuous if and only if the subspace topology on $\iota[A]$ is *coarser* than the topology comprised of sets $\iota[U]$ with $U$ open in $A$.