# If $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $C$, prove that $A$ is dense in $C$.

Tags: general-topology

> If $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $C$, prove that $A$ is dense in $C$.

My instructor told me to look at closure of $A$ in $B$ and the closure of $A$ in $C$, but I'm not really seeing how this helps me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a metric space or topological space? If it's a metric space, there's an $\epsilon/2$ argument.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/314041/28900).

Comment: Topological space, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $A$ is not dense in $C$. Then for some $x \in C$ we know $x \notin \overline{A}$. By assumption we know $\overline{A} = B$ so $x \notin B$. Since $\overline{A}$ is closed and $\overline{A} = B$ then $B$ must be closed, so $B = \overline{B}$, and again we know $x \notin \overline{B}$. Thus, $\overline{B} \neq C$ as $x \in C$; a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Take any non-empty open subset $V$ of $C,$ and let $U:=B\cap V.$ Note that $U$ is non-empty (why?) and open in $B$ (why?). Hence, $U$ contains a point of $A$ (why?), and so $V$ contains a point of $A$ (why?).

What can we then conclude?

**Note**: This may not make sense to you, depending on what your definition of "dense in [whatever]" is. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Recall that $X$ is dense in $Y$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}(X)\cap Y=Y$. Calculate $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ and $\operatorname{cl}(B)$ with respect to $C$.